# Android neighboring cells info

Tags: android

I am using Samsung Ace S5830 phone running on Android 2.2

I am facing a problem that when i try to get neighboring cell information it returns me an empty list. but when i get in the service mode of the phone with the code *#*#197328640#*#* and then click on neighboring cells it shows me the cell information.

Can anyone tell me why i am not able to get the neighboring cell information through programming? i am using the following code to get the neighboring cell info.

```
List neighboringList = telephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, the problem i faced was during to the make of the mobile phone, while i was trying to get this information on the samsung handsets or even LG handsets it doesnt give me the neighboring cells info even if they are available in the phone status and internal settings,

but when i tried to use the same code on the sony ericsson phone i was able to receive this information and along with many other which were not available on the samsung or lg handsets... i think it is due to the permissions that in samsung and LG user application cannot access this information but in SE it can.

that is what i found if someone has other finding or solution kindly please share.

regards,